# jQuery add target = _blank to all links that have a specific class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add attribute target =_blank to all links that have specific classes. Example:

```
<a class="something sometingelse" href="http://www.domain.com">my link</a>
```

How can I target only the links that have the classes: `something sometingelse` ?

I was trying this so far:

```
$('.something .sometingelse').attr('target', '_blank');
```

There are links that have class "something" and these should be open in same page so that's why I have to apply it to all links that have both classes.

Comment: Remove the space from `$('.something .sometingelse')`

Comment: @lesssugar: Thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

When you put a space between class names in a selector it means you are looking for an element with class "somethingelse" that is contained within an element with class "something".

That is not the case in your code.

Try changing the selector to use just the "somethingelse" class or both classes without a space between them.

Best of luck.